# how to create greater than and less than filter in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, slider

I am trying to use range slider in angularjs to filter the grid. I want a greater than and less than filter in my ng-repeat. But I am not getting how to do this. I am using the following code for now. But this is not working for me. This code is not giving me desired output

Here is my html for grid

```
<div class="col-md-3 product-left-grid" ng-repeat="data in Products| filter:priceSlider.max |filter:priceSlider.min">
    <div class="product-grid"></div>
    <div class="product-grid-text">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <img alt="" src="{{data.Picture1}}">
        </a>
        <div class="products-grid-info">
            <div class="price">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-width btn-default btn-font-weight" 
                   href="javascript:void(0)" 
                   ng-click="viewDetails($index)">Quick View</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                   class="btn btn-sm btn-width btn-default btn-font-weight" 
                   ng-click="addToCart (data.ProductID,data.Picture1,data.ProductName,data.UnitPrice,data.Discount,data.ShippingCharges,data.wieght)">Add to cart</a>
                <div class="tovar_description clearfix">
                    <a class="tovar_title" href="#"><b>{{data.ProductName}} </b> |  {{data.UnitPrice | currency:mycurrency}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my price range slider

```
<rzslider rz-slider-floor="priceSlider.floor"
          rz-slider-ceil="priceSlider.ceil"
          rz-slider-model="priceSlider.min"
          rz-slider-high="priceSlider.max"
          rz-slider-on-change="onSliderChange()"></rzslider>
```

Now I am using filter but I have doubt that I am going wrong somewhere. Please experts help to solve this problem. Price range filter I need like every eCommerce website have.

Thanks

Comment: you will need to create a custom filter

Comment: i am trying but its not working can u please refer me a working example

Answer (score 5):

You have to make a custom filter :

```
//create an angular filter named "price"
app.filter('price', function () {
    //our function will need three arguments 
    return function(items, greaterThan, lowerThan) { 
        //then we filter the array with dedicated ES5 method
        items = items.filter(function(item){
            //if item price is included between the two boundaries we return true
            return item.price > greaterThan && item.price < lowerThan;
        });

        //then we return the filtered items array
        return items;
    };
});
```

You can see how `Array.filter()` works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter)

Our function will need 3 arguments to work, the items list which is passed by default and the lower and higher boundaries that we will pass as arguments in our `ng-repeat` filter.

Then you can use the filter as follow :

```
<div ng-repeat="data in Products | price:priceSlider.min:priceSlider.max | orderBy:'price'">...</div>
```

As I said above, items array is passed by default, then, to specify other parameters you have to separate them with a colon `:` right after the filter name.

You can read about custom filters in the official documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09).

Finally you can then specified as many other filters as you want by separating them with a pipe `|`.
In our example I'm ordering them by price after the array has been filtered.

Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/freezystem/a8khu8kL/).

Comment: Is that answer useful to you ? You don't have made any feedback. Do you need some explanation ?